# RailsTutorial 3.2 Ch 11 - PostgreSQL syntax error breaks the status feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, syntax, railstutorial.org

I'm in [Section 11.3.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.2#sec%3amotivation_and_strategy) of the Rails Tutorial, and all tests were passing prior to this. Afterward, the home page (which has the micropost feed) breaks with this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "98, 1"
LINE 1: ...CT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts"  WHERE (user_id IN ('98, 1') O...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts"  WHERE (user_id IN ('98, 1') OR user_id = 101)
```

And several of the tests fail with a similar issue. Here's the first one:

```
1) Authentication authorization as wrong user visiting Users#edit page 
   Failure/Error: before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
   ActionView::Template::Error:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
   LINE 1: ...CT COUNT(*) FROM "microposts"  WHERE (user_id IN ('') OR use...
                                                                ^
```

Now, I am using PostgreSQL instead of the default SQLite3, so it may be that there is a syntax conflict, but I'm not positive. I'm not super familiar with Postgres (just using it to make the Heroku deploy cleaner).

It looks like the home page error is coming from the ids being passed to the query with quotes - I went into psql to test a few queries and this is successful:

```
SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" IN (1,2,3);
```

while this fails:

```
SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" IN ('1,2,3');
```

And the spec error is coming from an empty array being passed, equivalent to this, which also fails:

```
SELECT "microposts".* FROM "microposts" WHERE "microposts"."id" IN ('');
```

---

**Can anyone who is familiar with PostgreSQL syntax tell me how to rewrite the method definition to fix this issue?**

The current method in `micropost.rb` looks like this:

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids.join(', ')
    where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", followed_user_ids, user)
end
```

And the call from `users.rb' looks like this:

```
def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

Comment: prepared statements fail when you're doing stuff like building an `IN(...)` list - the preparer is rather stupid and doesn't realize it should be a comma-separated list, not a single solid chunk of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Holy crap, I actually figured this out myself. Just had to remove the join in the method definition:

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids
    where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", followed_user_ids, user)
end
```

`user.followed_user_ids.join(', ')` produces this: "1, 2, 3"

while

`user.followed_user_ids` produces this: 1, 2, 3

which is what I wanted.

Comment: Right. If you `join` in Ruby you get a single string which AR will quote; but PostgreSQL doesn't know what `int IN (string)` means so you get an error. If you hand `where` an array, it will quote each element (as needed), join the quoted elements with commas, and dump the result into the SQL; PostgreSQL does know what `int IN (int, int, ...)` means so it works. BTW, you can accept your own answers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a postgres issue so much as a bug in the tutorial, no?

Comment: True, though I didn't realize it until after I found the answer. I emailed the author about it and he said it was a genuine bug and will be fixed in the next revision (probably already is).