# Rails Tutorial 3.2 Ch11 SQL syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I am learning rails from rails tutorial. I got a problem in the [Section 11.3.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.2#sec:motivation_and_strategy), the code in the Listing 11.44:

```
def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
  followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids.join(', ')
  where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", followed_user_ids, user)
end
```

will not return user_id in followed_user_ids.

After searching at stackoverflow, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397954/railstutorial-3-2-ch-11-postgresql-syntax-error-breaks-the-status-feed), which said that just remove the "join" method and it works for me.

But I am curious about why there is no error when I run RSPEC before remove the "join" method.

In Listing 11.41:

```
subject { Micropost.from_users_followed_by(user) }

it { should include(own_post) }
it { should include(followed_post) }
```

If the "join" method will make the SQL statement wrong, why RSPEC passed?

Does anyone have the same problem?

## Update 2012.04.03

I used rails console to check the problem.

```
user = User.first
ids = ids = user.following_users.map(&:id).join(', ')
```

Which got

```
User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "follows" ON
"follows"."followable_id" = "users"."id" AND "follows"."followable_type" = 'User' WHERE    
"follows"."blocked" = 'f' AND "follows"."follower_id" = 1 AND "follows"."follower_type" 
= 'User' AND "follows"."followable_type" = 'User'
=> "6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,    
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 55, 56, 5"
```

Then the SQL

```
Collection.where("user_id IN (?)", ids)
```

The result is

```
Collection Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE (user_id IN 
('6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
52, 55, 56, 5')) ORDER BY collections.created_at DESC
=> []
```

Which return an empty array.

But I got all my rspec passed. Still no idea.

Comment: Does the test environment run on postgres too ?

Comment: the test and development environment run on SQLite .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the join creates a string `'1,2,3'`, then perhaps you want to `join("','")` to have `('1','2','3')`, but I don't think this will work - I'm sure PostgreSQL doesn't like IDs as strings.

Alternatively:

[Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) is a good SQL syntax gem where you could use:

```
user = User.first
ids = user.following_users.map(&:id)
Collection.where{(user_id.like_any ids)}
```

This will allow you to pass in the array of integers and Squeel will setup the query where:

```
SELECT "collections".* FROM "collections" WHERE (("collections"."user_id" LIKE 1 OR "collections"."user_id" LIKE 2 OR "collections"."user_id" LIKE 3))
```

EDIT: You can also use the syntax:

```
ids = User.first.following_users.pluck(:id)
Collection.find_by_user_id(ids)
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But what I really concern is why it got pass when I run the Rspec test,  but can not work when running the app.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't like IDs given as strings AFAIK. Pure speculation but why don't you try my suggestion, with Squeel.

Comment: Could I get a 1up if you found it useful? Helps the world go round ;)